# .NET - Set variable to default gateway

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am trying to set a variable (`dfgt`) to the default gateway from someone's computer. When you click a button the variable is then set by calling a function (`getDF`). So far I have found out how to get the value and output it, however whenever I try to set a variable to the returned result I get the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "192.168.1.254" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

My function is as follows

```
Private Function getDG() As Integer
    For Each adapter As NetworkInterface In myNetworkAdapters
        myAdapterProps = adapter.GetIPProperties

        myGateways = myAdapterProps.GatewayAddresses

        For Each Gateway As GatewayIPAddressInformation In myGateways
            'MessageBox.Show(Gateway.Address.ToString)
            Return Gateway.Address.ToString
        Next
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

This is how I set the variable

```
Private Sub Unblock_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Unblock.Click

    Dim dfgt As String

    dfgt = getDG()

End Sub
```

I am rather new to .NET, I apologize in advance if I have failed to provide you with enough information.

Comment: Look to see where you could be casting a string to an integer. Can you point to the line the exception throws on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the function like this:

> Private Function getDG() **As Integer**

but try to return a value like this:

> Return Gateway.Address.**ToString**

See the problem here?

Comment: Yes, I see the problem!
Thanks very much, Joel.